# Spark dataframe CSV vs Parquet

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am beginner in Spark and trying to understand the mechanics of spark dataframes.
I am comparing performance of sql queries on spark sql dataframe when loading data from csv verses parquet. My understanding is once the data is loaded to a spark dataframe, it shouldn't matter where the data was sourced from (csv or parquet). However I see significant performance difference between the two. I am loading the data using the following commands and there writing queries against it.

```
dataframe_csv = sqlcontext.read.format("csv").load()

dataframe_parquet = sqlcontext.read.parquet()
```

Please explain the reason for the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is querying against a Spark DataFrame based on CSV faster than one based on Parquet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541315/is-querying-against-a-spark-dataframe-based-on-csv-faster-than-one-based-on-parq)

Comment: Can you clarify where you're seeing the performance difference? Is it when you actually run a spark sql query after you read from csv/parquet? Spark has lazy evaluation for dataframes. If you're timing how long it takes to execute an action (e.g., .show(), .count(), etc.) on the sql query dataframe, it will most likely include the time to read from the csv/parquet. As a result, parquet should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

The reason because you see differente performance between csv & parquet is because parquet has a columnar storage and csv has plain text format. Columnar storage is better for achieve lower storage size but plain text is faster at read from a dataframe.