# How to maximise single-machine Dask performance for from-rest group by?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have a large CSV which I read into Dask and perform a group-by like so

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
aa = dd.read_csv("large.csv")

# takes 20 seconds
aa.var0.value_counts().compute()
```

And it takes 20 seconds.

However, if I store the data as parquet then the same operation only takes 7 seconds.

```py
aa.to_parquet("large.parquet")
aa = dd.read_parquet("large.parquet")

# takes 7 seconds
aa.var0.value_counts().compute()
```

Are there anything extra I can do to speed this up further? The general problem is this: I have a dataset that sits on a hard drive (the data format is not restricted, but I only have one machine, so no clusters), how to maximise the performance a simple group-by operation where the data starts on disk (i.e. not already loaded into RAM)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can further speed it up by loading only one column

```r
aa = dd.read_parquet("large.parquet", columns = ["var0"])

# takes 7 seconds
aa.var0.value_counts().compute()
```

There may be more that can be done e.g. ensure that Dask is using more workers.

Comment: For a single large parquet dataset, selecting only the columns you need will provide a performance boost. Other optimizations will be more query specific. see https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not particular to dask, but rather due to the way CSV and parquet are formatted.

See [Is querying against a Spark DataFrame based on CSV faster than one based on Parquet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541315/is-querying-against-a-spark-dataframe-based-on-csv-faster-than-one-based-on-parq)